# Shopware remove save button from plugin config

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Is there a way to remove the `save` button from plugin config or to overwrite it with our own action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be more difficult to remove the button just for your extension. But you can override the click handler of the component with specific logic for your extension's domain only and call the original handler for other domains:

```js
const { Component } = Shopware;

Component.override('sw-extension-config', {
    computed: {
        domain() {
            return this.$super('domain');
        }
    },

    methods: {
        onSave() {
            if (this.domain === 'YourTechnicalPluginName.config') {
                console.log('do what you want');

                return;
            }

            this.$super('onSave');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. another small question , how can i access salesChannelId in there ?

Comment: answer : this.$refs.systemConfig.currentSalesChannelId